# Silverlight Ria services Acces To Operation was denied

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-membership, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services, ria

Currently we have a silverlight application that works out of browser, somethimes the silverlight application cannot connect to the server via the RIA services, if I log the error on the server I get following error:

```
 Access to operation 'XXXX' was denied.:
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.ValidateMethodPermissions(DomainOperationEntry domainOperationEntry, Object entity)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.ValidateMethodCall(DomainOperationEntry domainOperationEntry, Object[] parameters, List`1 validationResults)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.Query(QueryDescription queryDescription, IEnumerable`1& validationErrors, Int32& totalCount)Inner Exception:
```

The annoying part is that this error is not reproducable, it occurs sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates you probably have a RequiresRole on the query method and the current user (lack of a logged in user) is not in the required role. ValidateMethodPermissions is where the DomainService is checking is the user has permissions to call that query.